# Indent to border

Tags: html, css, border

Can you please tell me how to indent the border? I've tried `padding-top/bottom` - it lowers or raises the whole block at once.

[image]

When I try to step back from the lower boundary, only my block - TAB 1 - rises, the boarder itself stands still.

If I move away from the block where I have hung the `border` itself, the border rises and I don't get the warp like I showed in the picture above.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="tabs">
            <div class="tabs first__tab">
               <div class="tabs first__tab__bookmark">TAB 1</div>
                   <div class="tabs first__tab__content">
                      <h1 class="tabs first__tab__title__text">Tabs with soft transitioning effect.</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.first__tab {
    display: flex;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;

.first__tab__content {
    width: 570px;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
```

Could the problem be that I have nowhere to fall back on?

[image]

Comment: Can you shere your fiddle, pen or sniped?

Comment: it's not an Indent of a border. Those are 2 elements with incomplete borders.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can implement this? @tacoshy